# error CS0117: `UnityEditor.PlayerSettings' does not contain a definition for `mobileMTRendering'

Tags: unity-game-engine

Since I did an Unity update I can't build my videoplayer.

> Assets/AVProVideo/Scripts/Editor/MediaPlayerEditor.cs(293,50): error CS0117: 'UnityEditor.PlayerSettings' does not contain a definition for 'mobileMTRendering'

I'm on Unity 2017.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity 2017.1 seems to provide a new function :

```
PlayerSettings.SetMobileMTRendering(BuildTargetGroup.iOS, true);
PlayerSettings.SetMobileMTRendering(BuildTargetGroup.Android, true);
```

Source : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.SetMobileMTRendering.html